# How is the error calculated in ETS using R?

Tags: r, forecasting, excel

I'm trying to replicate the ETS algorithms from R in Excel using the formulas present in the link below. 
https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7

According to my research the error is supposed to be distributed normally: $e_t = \varepsilon_t∼NID(0, \sigma^2)$, so $\varepsilon_t$ might be random.

But the ETS forecast result from R is always the same, so the error is constant?

Does any one know how I could calculate $\varepsilon_t$ in Excel (not giving circular references), so my forecast can match the one in R?

Comment: "so i might be random": what's i?

Comment: Fitting ETS model usually involves finding MLE estimate, i.e. solving non-linear maximisation problem. Excel is not famous for its non-linear optimisation problem solving.

Comment: @mpiktas Excel has an excellent nonlinear optimization algorithm based on GRG method, in addition now they also have evolutionary algorithm in their [solver](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-help) and have been using it for almost a decade and have had no issues. GRG and genetic algorithms are proven methods. It is very popular among engineers and financial modelers.

Answer (score 1):

The $e_t$ are *in-sample residuals*, i.e., the difference between the historical data and the model fit. You can obtain these like this:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- ets(USAccDeaths)
fit$residuals
hist(fit$residuals)
```

[image: residuals]

Your forecast will be constant if `ets()` determines that a simple model without trend and seasonality is the best fit to your data. Your future *actuals* will likely not be constant. So your future errors will again *not* be constant.

Comment: Thank's for your answer,                                       but what i would like to know is how to calculate the εt,      it's a random generated number respecting the NID ? or                the error is calculated, but how without having a circular reference in excel?

Comment: Well, they are the residuals. $e_t=y_t-\hat{y}_t$, where $y_t$ are your observed actuals, and $\hat{y}_t$ are your ETS in-sample fit. (Possibly with $y_t$ and $\hat{y}_t$ reversed, there are various schools of thought on how residuals are defined.) I assume you are not asking how to re-implement `ets()` in Excel, because that would be a somewhat large project for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the model you plan on using, i.e multiplicative or additive error. Please see table given below, which from Forecasting:Principles and Practice
[image]

The table is for multiplicative error, now for additive trend and multiplicative seasonality (set of equations in 3rd column and 2nd row) you can find the error equation by working backwards for the equation of $y_t$

$\epsilon_t$ = ( $y_t$/ (($l_{t-1}$ + $b_{t-1}$)*$s_{t-m}$) ) - 1

where $t$ is the current period and ${t-1}$ is the previous period. $y_t$ represents actual demand in the current period. $l_{t-1}$ and $b_{t-1}$ are the level and trend values respectively for the previous period. $m$ is the seasonal period of the data. This way you can recursively calculate error values for all the periods of the time series you have. Working in a similar fashion you find error terms for any model you plan to use viz., MAM, AAM, etc.

I implement the above formula in excel sheet and the values I got matched the ones I saw in R. I use the ***ets*** model within the ***forecast*** package in R